# Robot Framework Element Visibility

Tags: robotframework

For the keyword: `Element Should Be Visible` in Robot Framework, it is written that it gives a logical visibility not optical. What does that mean? I do not get the idea!
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the keyword decides by inspecting the DOM, by checking certain HTML attributes that indicate or could indicate visibility.

The documentation of the keyword further says:

> For example, an element that carries `display:none` is not logically visible, so using this keyword on that element would fail.

Comment: Thank you @Bence Kaulics. Can I use this Keyword to validate that an element is visible?

Comment: @NaCbank Possibly, depending on the application.